# Salesforce Git Pipeline not recognizing sfdx

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, git

I am setting up my CI/CD pipelines and when i am running the pipeline , it fails with the below error.

/bin/bash: line 129: sfdx: command not found

[image]

Below is my sample .yml file

```
####################################################
# The docker image the jobs initialize with.
# We use nodejs, so a node image makes sense.
# https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#image
####################################################
image: "node:latest"

stages:
- Build
- Test
- Staging
- Production
- ".post"
checkDeploy:
  stage: Build
  except:
    refs:
    - develop
    - master
  when: manual
  allow_failure: true
  environment:
    name: INTEGRATION
  script:
  - echo "Authenticate - $CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME Environment"
  - sfdx auth:sfdxurl:store --sfdxurlfile $QA_AUTH_URL -s -a $CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME
  - sfdx force:source:deploy -p $ROOTDIR -c --testlevel $TESTLEVEL
deploy-qa:
  stage: Test
  only:
    refs:
    - develop
  allow_failure: false
  environment:
    name: QA
  script:
  - echo "Authenticate - QA Environment"
  - sfdx auth:sfdxurl:store --sfdxurlfile $QA_AUTH_URL -s -a $CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME
  - echo "Deploy SF metadata..."
deploy-uat:
  stage: Staging
  only:
    refs:
    - Release
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
  environment:
    name: UAT
  script:
  - echo "Authenticate - UAT Environment"
  - sfdx auth:sfdxurl:store --sfdxurlfile $UAT_AUTH_URL -s -a $CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME
  - echo "Deploy SF metadata..."
deploy-production:
  stage: Production
  only:
    refs:
    - master
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
  environment:
    name: PROD
  script:
  - echo "Authenticate - Prod Environment"
  - sfdx auth:sfdxurl:store --sfdxurlfile $PROD_AUTH_URL -s -a $CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME
  - echo "Deploy SF metadata..."
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your job doesn't contain any steps that install the Salesforce CLI, which is not available in a vanilla NodeJS Docker image.

Installation routes are documented in the [Salesforce DX Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm#sfdx_setup_install_cli_linux); you can choose to download and extract a tarball:

```
wget https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx-linux-amd64.tar.xz
mkdir sfdx
tar xJf sfdx-linux-amd64.tar.xz -C sfdx --strip-components 1
./sfdx/install
```

or install using Node:

```
npm install sfdx-cli --global
```